# $z^3+z^2+z+k=0$, $z_1=-i$ what is the other complex root stating whether it is real or complex?

Tags: complex-numbers

This question I have been stuck on for a while I figured out what $k$ is but I cant find the $z_2$  and $z_3$ this is my working out. Any help is much appreciated thank you. [My work so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBoVX.jpg).The answer is $z_2=i$ and $_3=−1$ but I don't know how to get to it.

Comment: It is impossible to read your document

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: If you know one of the root, $z_1 = i$ substitute it into the equation to get the value of $k$

Comment: @Aderinsola Joshua i have and got k=1 but I cant find the other roots.

Comment: That means $z^3+z^2+z+1 = (z-i)\cdot (z^2+az+b)$, can you find the value of $a$ and $b$

Comment: $ z^3+z^2+z+1 = z^3+az^2+bz-iz^2-aiz-bi = z^3+(a-i)z^2+(b-ai)z-bi$, now if you compare the two equation you will see that $a-i =1, b-ai =1, -bi = 1$ therefore $$a= 1+i, b= i$$ can you solve $z^2+(1+i)z+i$

Comment: @Aderinsola Joshua thank you for helping me I am going to try it now but the 1 comment why do you white b and not 1?

Comment: @Aderinsola Joshua i am so sorry i realized that the $z_1=i$ but that was wrong I don't know how that changed but it was spouse to be  $z_1=-i$ is it the same but opposite sign so z+i?

Comment: @Aderinsola Joshua i got $(z+i)(z^2+(1-i)z-i)$ what do i do from here do i use the quadratic formula ? and i am still confused why you wrote b if you could explain that please?

Comment: Yes use the quadratic formula

Comment: $b$ is from the quadratic $z^2+az+b$ , you said the first root $z_1$ is $-i$ that means that $z+i=0$

Comment: @Aderinsola Joshuai tried doing the quadratic formula i got error on my calculator?

Comment: @Aderinsola Joshua what should i do now

Comment: @Sara I saw what you wear talking about, sorry I made a mistake writing, if $$z^3+z^2+z+1 = (z+i)\cdot (z^2+az+b)$$.   $$ z^3+z^2+z+1 = z^3+az^2+bz+iz^2+aiz+bi$$.   $$z^3+z^2+z+1 = z^3+(a+i)z^2+(b+ai)z+bi$$.    If you compare the two equations, $$ a+i = 1, b+ai = 1, bi = 1$$ you will see that $b = -i $ and $a = 1-i$ $$ z^3+z^2+z+1 = (z+i)(z^2+(1-i)z-i)$$ now you have to solve the quadratic... So try using the quadratic formula on paper

Comment: @Aderinsola Joshua thank you very much i finally got it.

Comment: @Sara if I solve the quadratic $$ z^2+(1-i)z-i$$ you can try a scientific calculator which can handle complex number or a cas $$ z = \frac{ -(1-i) \pm \sqrt{ (1-i)^2-4(-i)} }{2}$$ $$ z = \frac{ -(1-i) \pm \sqrt{ 1-2i-1+4i} }{2}$$. $$z = \frac{ -1+i \pm \sqrt{ 2i} }{2}$$. To bad this process is requesting for the Square root of $i$ and you're not familiar with that also... just so you know $\sqrt(2i) = i+1$. $$ z = \frac{ (-1+i) \pm (i+1) }{2}$$ can you finish it from here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @lab bhattacharjee already answered, the problem is simple if $k$ is a real number and you have the three solutions.

Now, if $k$ is complex, use the long division to have the quadratic
$$\frac{z^3+z^2+z+k} {z+i}=(i k+(1-i)) z^2+(k-i) z-i k$$ for which
$$\Delta=-3 k^2+(4+2 i) k-1$$ Let $k=a+ib$ to make
$$\Delta=(-3 a^2+4 a+3 b^2-2 b-1)+2 (a+2 b-3ab)i$$ If the imaginary part is equal to $0$, then $b=\frac{a}{3 a-2}$ and then
$$\Delta=\frac{-27 a^4+72 a^3-72 a^2+32 a-4}{(2-3 a)^2}$$and the quartic write
$$-9\left(a-\frac{2+\sqrt{2}}{3} \right) \left(a-\frac{2-\sqrt{2}}{3}
   \right)(3 a^2-4 a+2)$$ So, continue looking at the sign of
$$-\left(a-\frac{2+\sqrt{2}}{3} \right) \left(a-\frac{2-\sqrt{2}}{3}
   \right)$$

Comment: i am so confused how does this become the answer which is $z_2=i  $and $z_3=-1$ and real which is written on the back of my book?

Comment: @Sara. There is no problem if $k$ is real.

Comment: but the thing is $z_1=i$ so shouldnt the factor equal to $z_1-i$ so divide it by this i don't know but I am spouse to land and the answers $z_2=i$ and $z_3=-1$ and have been stuck on this question since yesterday

Answer (score 1):

Once you have $z^3+z^2+z+1 = 0$, this is equivalent to $\frac{z^4 - 1}{z - 1} = 0$ as it is a geometric progression with first term $1$ and common ratio $z$. Note that $z = 1$ is not a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Complex conjugate root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate_root_theorem)

$i$ will be another root

If the third root is $a$ by Vieta's formula $$-\dfrac11=a+i+(-i)\iff a=-1$$

$$-\dfrac k1=i(-i)a=?$$